# stateprovider on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my first time asking on stackoverflow so please bear with me if I'm not clear enough with the problem. I am working on a flight booking web application as a university project. I'm using MEAN stack and the site is visible on 52.27.150.19. It used to work fine on both PC and mobile phones until I started using ui-router states instead of using ngRoute's $routeProvider. Now on phones, it doesn't even run the javascript animations or call any of the ng-click functions when I click on any buttons. Here's what my $stateProvider does:

```
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
        controller: 'ctrl'
    })
    .state('away', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
        controller: 'away'
    })

.state('book', {
    templateUrl: '/../partials/Book.html',
    controller: 'bookingCtrl',
})

.state('flightStatus', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/flightStatus.html',
        controller: 'flightStatusCtrl'
    })
    .state('outgoing', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/outgoingFlights.html',
        controller: 'outgoingFlightsCtrl'

    })
    .state('myFlightResults', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/myFlightResults.html',
        controller: 'myFlightResultsCtrl'
    })
    .state('myFlights', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/myFlights.html',
        controller: 'myFlightsCtrl'
    })
    .state('flightStatusResultsDate', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/flightStatusResults.html',
        controller: 'flightStatusResultsDate'
    })
    .state('flightStatusResultsPlace', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/flightStatusResults.html',
        controller: 'flightStatusResultsPlace'
    })
    .state('payment', {
        templateUrl:'../partials/payment.html',
        controller: 'paymentCtrl'
    })
    .state('confirm', {
        templateUrl:'../partials/confirmation.html',
        controller: 'confirm'
    })

    .state('return', {

        templateUrl: '../partials/outgoingFlights.html',
        controller: 'returnFlightsCtrl'
    });
});
```

and I've made sure that the home state is the inital state:

```
App.run(function($state){
$state.go('home');
})
```

It seems like the javascript just dies on phones, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest to use $urlProvider.otherwise("/home"); at the top of your App.config part. And add url attribute for every state. And remove your last code block App.run...

Comment: i agrre with Niels, ui-router mayb be crashing when injecting it on the app.run because he can't resolve initial state. Furthermore for a proper stat configuration you must have at least one state with url define as '' to be the root state.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it without adding urls? The main reason I opted for the stateProvider is that the url would stay the same as the user changed views.

Comment: @Sayegh The main principle of routing is that it's url based. It's impossible to have the url fixed and still implement routing. Please check documentation of ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Each state needs an url attribute is my guess, so change this

```
.state('confirm', {
        templateUrl:'../partials/confirmation.html',
        controller: 'confirm'
    })
```

to this

```
.state('confirm', {
        url: '/confirm',
        templateUrl:'../partials/confirmation.html',
        controller: 'confirm'
    })
```